# UIPanGestureRecognizer not working on iOS5

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios5, uigesturerecognizer

Situation is like this
I have a `UIImageView` say **imvObj** in a UIView say **vwObj** and this whole setup is inside a `UITableViewCell`. I have added `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on **vwObj** . This thing is working very good on `iOS` < **5.0**.
Please help.

**EDIT**

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(someOtherMethod:)];
    [panGesture setDelegate:self];
    [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [vwObj addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
    [panGesture release];
```

**Solution**

just removed following line and issue was solved

```
    [panGesture setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: This is not enough information. It isn't enough to "add UIPanGestureRecognizer"; it doesn't do anything all by itself. You have to have an action handler that responds to the gesture recognizer. Explain how this is set up, show code, and state clearly what is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution.
I was doing one wrong thing, I was setting delegate of gesture after setting its target to self. So following line caused this issue in `iOS5`

```
[panGesture setDelegate:self];
```

Once i removed it the problem was solved.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment as the answer was in your question -- I'm still confused though. What if you NEED to set delegate to self, e.g. when using shouldSimultaneouslyRecognize or whatever that one was called?

Answer (score 4):

I think you just forgot to enable userInteraction for the imageview.

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: That didn't work. I tried it already. I even removed the imageView but even simple UIView is not listening to gesture.

Comment: THANK YOU! Totally what I was missing!

Comment: Somehow this was easy to miss in Apple's documentation. Thank you!